# Jquery: controlling duplicate class's (or divs) seperatly

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table

I'm listing records from a database inside a `<table>`.
The number of records is stochastic.

I wish for the user to be able to select a specific row from the table, and then for a space to appear between the row selected & the next. This space will give additional details from the database about that specific record.

```
<tr class ="referal">
      <td><?php echo $referral['CustomerCode'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $referral['PhoneNumber'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $referral['TimeStamp'];?></td>
      <td><div id="toggle"><input type="button" value="+"/></div></td>

</tr>

<tr class="extra">
     <td>Hello, World!</td>
</tr>
```

`Foreach` of the records, I use the above code. Hello, world! representing the additional space in question.

So far I have been successful using jQuery's `.slideToggle()` to achieve this, however as I am using the same class, `.extra` for each of the records additional space, clicking on one of the records invokes all of the record's spaces to show

If I could determine the number of records, then I could use PHP to write out a separate class for each record. However, in my circumstances I am unable to do this.

(it should be noted that this will be part of an overall 'dynamic' interface that is continually updating to the number of records from a number of tables)

**My Question:**
How do I go about this? controlling duplicate instances of code (& class/div) separately.

Comment: Isn't this more of a JavaScript question than a PHP question?

Comment: This is still a JQuery issue. Look up using .this

Comment: i will edit to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable by default the extra informations divs:

```
tr.extra {
    display: none;
}
```

Then using jQuery you can easily detect when an element is clicked and work on the element right next to it.

```
$("tr.referal").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Slight edit:
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".referal").click(function(){
                    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
                  });
        });